# Youtube API Authentication - Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, ios-simulator, youtube-api

I am trying to upload video using sample code of youtube api. 
When i press upload button, the progress bar finishes its process, but once when it reaches end of point i get error. Error description is as follows :

> YouTubeTest[2149:f803] error - Error
>   Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.google.GDataServiceDomain error 400.)"
>   UserInfo=0x69d5bd0 {}

This is code for upload button pressed

```
- (IBAction)uploadPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *devKey = [mDeveloperKeyField text];

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

    NSString *username = [mUsernameField text];
    NSString *clientID = [mClientIDField text];

    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username
                                                             clientID:clientID];

    // load the file data
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubeTest" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];

    // gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
    NSString *titleStr = [mTitleField text];
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

    NSString *categoryStr = [mCategoryField text];
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

    NSString *descStr = [mDescriptionField text];
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

    NSString *keywordsStr = [mKeywordsField text];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

    BOOL isPrivate = mIsPrivate;

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    // create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file data
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                          data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:filename];

    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];

}
```

I have set up developer key and client key correctly from API Dashboard.

I am running this on simulator. Is it we can not upload videos from simulator?

Please guide me where am i going wrong?

Comment: A 400 error commonly means bad request. I would check over all your code, login authentication and if possible, test on device to rule out any possible issues that the simulator may be causing.

Comment: @Luke I checked it on device too. Its not working there either.. Giving same error :(

Comment: Have you got any sample code or link then please share.I got samples for MAC OS X but bot for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error Solved... 
When using a Google account to upload video to YouTube, some functions of the GData 
Objective-C require the Gmail account as parameter and some require 
the YouTube linked account as parameter.

When you call '- (void)setUserCredentialsWithUsername:(NSString *) 
username password:(NSString *)password;' in GDataServiceBase, the 
username should be the Gmail account, for example 
'x...@gmail.com' and the password should be the password of the 
Gmail account.

But when you call '+ (NSURL *)youTubeUploadURLForUserID:(NSString *) 
userID clientID:(NSString *)clientID;' in GDataServiceGoogleYouTube, 
the userID parameter should be the YouTube linked account and the 
password the password of the Gmail account.

I was using email_id@gmail.com to log in where now i am just using email_id to log in. What a silly error!.. But took me 2 full days to solve.. Duhhh..!!