# Trying to direct upload via Youtube API and getting Invalid Request (NSURLErrorDomain error 400.)

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'm trying to direct upload a video to Youtube via the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading). I can't figure out where the problem is...is it my request URL syntax? Is there something wrong with the way I'm adding the video file to the body? (I'm using MKNetworkkit as my request engine.)

Here is my code:

```
    //*********************************************************
    //* Setup the request URL and params
    //*********************************************************

    NSString *baseUrl = @"http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
    NSString *_accessToken = // the google API access token
    NSString *xml = 
    @"<?xml version='1.0'>"
    "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"
    "xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'"
    "xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'/>"
      "<media:group>"
        "<media:title type='plain'>My Video Title</media:title>"
        "<media:description type='plain'>"
        "This is a test video. Hopefully it'll upload to Youtube succesfully."
        "</media:description>"
        "<media:category"
        "scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>People"
        "</media:category>"
        "<media:keywords>test, video</media:keywords>"
      "</media:group>"
    "</entry>";
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _accessToken, @"access_token",
                                   myYouTubeDeveloperKey, @"DEVELOPER_KEY",
                                   @"vid1.mp4", @"VIDEO_FILENAME",
                                   xml, @"API_XML_Request",
                                   nil];

    //*********************************************************
    //* Configure the request
    //*********************************************************
    MKNetworkOperation *op = [globalMKNetworkEngine operationWithURLString:baseUrl params:params httpMethod:@"POST"];
    [op addFile:[[self getVideoFileURL] absoluteString] forKey:@"Binary File Data"];
    [op onUploadProgressChanged:^(double progress) {
        NSLog(@"progress: %@", progress);
        [uploadProgressBar setProgress:progress animated:YES];
    }];
    [op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *operation) {

        //*********************************************************
        //* On success, do this
        //*********************************************************

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSLog(@"Success!");
        });


    } onError:^(NSError *error) {
        DLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh..." message:@"There was a network error. Please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
    [globalMKNetworkEngine enqueueOperation:op];
```

Here is the response as reported by MKNetworkKit:

```
 Danceplanet[16449:707] -[MKNetworkOperation     operationFailedWithError:]
Request
-------
curl -X POST "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads" \
-F     "VIDEO_FILENAME=vid1" -F "DEVELOPER_KEY=(the developer key is here)" \
-F "access_token=(an access token)" -F "API_XML_Request=<?xml version='1.0'>\
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'/>\
<media:group>\
<media:title type='plain'>My Video Title</media:title>\
<media:description type='plain'>This is a test video. Hopefully it'll upload to Youtube succesfully.</media:description>\
<media:categoryscheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>People</media:category>\
<media:keywords>test, video</media:keywords>\
</media:group>\
</entry>" \
-F "Binary File Data=@file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/BBD79FFD-01D5-402C-995A-D9F9CE61F312/Documents/savedVideos/vid1.mp4;type=application/octet-stream"

--------
Response
--------
Invalid Request
, [The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 400.)]
 Danceplanet[16449:707] __block_global_3 [Line 167] The operation     couldn‚Äôt be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 400.)
 Danceplanet[16449:707] -[MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:]     [Line 1283] State: 0`
```

Comment: Is your API key and Access tokens are correct?

Comment: Yes...I'm using a DEFINE to point to my Developer Key and my access token is coming from a freshly used refresh token

Comment: Have you tried doing the request through some other way (browser plugin, curl command, etc.)? To discard that the problem is with the headers you are sending.

Comment: Also, take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986791/youtube-api-authentication-iphone and to this framework:  http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: From what I understand, the Youtube direct upload API is done via POST, so the GData framework is not needed. I'm using the instructions here https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading as a reference

Comment: What I mean is that I'm using Google's OAuth, not the gdata client library

Comment: Basically 400 is, I guess related to bad url syntax.

Comment: I posted my URL above...can you see something wrong with the syntax? Because it looks well-formed to me.

Comment: 400 is a general error code could be anything, not necessarily the url

Comment: refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698807/youtube-video-upload-using-nsurlrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on this approach and am now using the Google obj-c client library instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be whit the NSString

```
NSString * xmlEx =@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" 
                                "<Data xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
                                "<MediaFile>"
                                "<FileName>%@</FileName>"
                                "<Folder>%@</Folder>"
                                "</MediaFile>"
                                "</Data>"
```

This is how i write xml to string before i post. The problem might be with the special characters. Compere the XML version characters.